# When developing mobile compatible HTML apps, is there a way to specify that for a specific input[type=text] only numeric digits are allowed?

Tags: html, mobile

When developing mobile compatible HTML apps, is there a way to specify that for a specific `input[type=text]` only numeric digits are allowed?

I want the virtual keyboards to only show numbers.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

With HTML5, yes.

```
<input type="number" name="n">
```

Here is a link with all the new for types for input;
http://www.petefreitag.com/item/768.cfm

Comment: Of course, as the link demonstrates, that doesn’t necessarily force a numbers-only keypad on all phones. It is the nearest you can get with HTML though, unless I’m missing something.

Comment: Nope, you're correct--it's to the phones discretion.  I would, however, hope to see this becomes the standard as html5 support continues.

Comment: Yeah it seems odd that the iPhone doesn’t provide a numbers-only keyboard — it has one, for entering the passcode lock. Maybe they worried about HTML authors using the type incorrectly, or the spec changing to allow some non-numerical characters. I guess the spec allows floating point numbers? So you’d need to be able to add a decimal point?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute `pattern=[0-9]`. This is the logical way to specify that only digits are allowed. Browsers may or may not take this into account in their UI; currently, they don’t.

Using `type=number` specifies that the input data should be numeric, and this affects some browsers on mobile devices. But it is not expected to restrict data to digits (numbers may contain other characters too). It is more or less expected to create a “spinbox” control, and on some browsers, like Chrome, it already does that.

The important question is really what kind of data the field is to contain.

Answer (score 0):

I think recent mobile versions of WebKit support the HTML5 input type [`<input type="number">`](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-number) — see http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms.

It is up to each device’s browser to decide what interface to render though — there’s no way to guarantee that users will only be able to enter numbers. The link in [@OnResolve’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229188/20578) provides screenshots of what various iPhones and Android phones do with it.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5, you can set the attribute `type="number"`.
[Here is a test page for mobile.](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html)
[Here is the spec.](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#number-state-type-number)

Answer (score 0):

Yes bro `<input type="number">` 
here is a complete list of all input type.
http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-make-user-friendly-interface-for.html